# CodeIgniter - News Archive function

Tags: php, database, codeigniter

I'm doing a kind of archive in CodeIgniter, but I have a problem with my code. It only shows the latest "date" (or "subject" if that's the case).

```
function archive($id){
    $this->db->select('date');
    $this->db->distinct('date');
    $query = $this->db->get_where('news', array('page' => $id));

    $q_arr = $query->result_array();

    foreach($q_arr as $q1){
        $query2 = $this->db->get_where('news', array('date' => $q1['date']));

        $q2_arr = $query2->result_array();

        $archive = array();

        foreach($q2_arr as $q2){
            $archive[$q1['date']][] = $q2;
        }

    }

    return $archive;
}
```

In my database I have a coloum in my News table called date, where I manually put the date.

WHAT I WANT:

---

**19th of March**

News

News

News

---

**15th of March**

News

News

News

---

**Really hope someone can help!!**

Comment: You're using `get_where()` and specifying an ID -- wouldn't that only return one date row then?

Comment: No, that's just because I can use news on multiple pages. The page id has nothing to do with the rest of the function. If I return the $q_arr it shows all of the dates.

Comment: lose the distinct and your second query is overwriting the values for the array keys.

Comment: Even without the distinct it doesn't work, do you know why?

Comment: Never mind - I worked it out! I redefine the $archive as an array(); every single foreach. Thank you for your time though!